# Passing data from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have an Activity with two fragments and I need to pass a string from FragmentA to FragmentB.

To pass the data, I have this in my FragmentA:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FragmentB.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", "Mark");
    startActivity(intent);
```

And to get the data, I did this in FragmentB

```
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

    if(b!=null)
    {
        String name =(String) b.get("name");
        nameTextView.setText(name);
    }
```

But this is not working. Is there a specific way to pass a string from one fragment to another fragment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. If fragments are hosted by same activity-
   You cannot cast an intent to Fragment. Fragment acts as a part of Activity, it is not an activity by itself. So to share a string between fragments you can declare a static String in Activity. Access that string from Fragment A to set the value and Get the string value in fragment B.
2. Both fragments are hosted by different Activities-
   Then you can use putExtra to pass a string from Fragment A of Activity A to Activity B. Store that string in Activity B and use it in Fragment B.

Answer (score 4):

to pass data between Fragments you can use `setArguments(Bundle b)`. For instance:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

  public static FragmentA newInstance(String name) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", name);
    FragmentA f = new FragmentA(); 
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like below,

```
 Fragment fr=new friendfragment();
 FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
 android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("CID", "your value");
 fr.setArguments(args);
 ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
 ft.commit();
```

To receive the data do the following,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("CID");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in FragmentActivity 1 fragment A:

fb is the instance of the bean I created and ID is the parameter

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FragmentActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", fb.ID);
startActivity(intent);
```

Code in FragmentActivity 2 fragment Any:

```
fragmentA= (FragmentActivity2) getActivity();
String cust_id = fragmentA.getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
```