# Pass a String from a Fragment to another Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have the following model.

A TabFragment which extends Fragment.
A ListFragment which extends Fragment.
And a DetailFragment which extends Fragment.

TabFragment hosts ListFragment which will launch a DetailFragment.

When I call getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i); from DetailFragment, onActivityResult is called, but only in TabFragment. I pass from Detail Fragment, one String identifier to TabFragment.

My only problem is that I would like to pass this String from TabFragment back up to ListFragment.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is `i` variable?

Comment: an intent which has my string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing data from one fragment to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568339/passing-data-from-one-fragment-to-another)

Comment: what about using global variables for send any data from any class to another class? for example, Application's space

Comment: Kindly go through following link:-     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments

Comment: @TapaSave Global variables should be avoided. Consider multi-threading problems updating a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a fragment you need with FragmentManager's findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag() where id/tag is one you use whan you add a fragment. After that you can interact with this particular fragment.