# use listview selected item on one fragment to display text on other fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

i have two fragments one with a listview and the other with a textview, i want when an item is selected it's text is used to set text on a textview in another fragment and to display this other fragment.

so i have set an onItemClickListener on listview (lv) like this;

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {



String hh =  lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().toLowerCase();


    int resd = getResources().getIdentifier(hh, "raw", getPackageName());
    InputStream isd = getResources().openRawResource(resd); 
    BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isd));
    String lined; 
    String entireFiled = "";

    try {
        while((lined = brd.readLine()) != null) { 
            entireFiled += (lined + "\n"); 
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error reading file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     TextView output1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fp);    
    output1.setText(entireFiled);


        Family frag5 = new Family();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();       
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl, frag5).addToBackStack(null);    
        ft.commit();

            }
        });
```

The other fragment is called Family and its textview is output1. when i run it i get null exception at the textview line. so how do i do this? thank you

Comment: i used the answer [from this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568339/passing-data-from-one-fragment-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setArgument

```
Family frag5 = new Family();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("text", entireFiled);
frag5 .setArguments(args);
```

Get the value in Family Fragment OnCreateView Method

```
TextView output1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fp);  
String text =  getArguments().getString("text", "");
output1.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access another fragments textview like that.For communicating one fragment to another fragment try to use `Handler`.

Or in your case you can try to use Shared Preference.Save the data in the first fragment on button click. And when family fragment comes just retrieve the data from the shared preference and show it in the text view from the  family fragment.

Comment: how do i use the handler? am a newbie

Comment: check it http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html