# In A NavigationDrawer : How to get data from several fragments in another fragment?

Tags: android

I am developping an app to gather data which are in a Drawer.
I have an app with :
One Activity
A NavigationDrawer with 6 fragments

Each of 5 Fragment contain 1 TextView and and SPinners and I want to gather and show data from thoses Spinners and TextVieww in the Fragment 6.

Actually I Want to put a Button in each Fragment and when I click on the button the Data is passed to Fragment 6. 
So I want to be able to do that for each Fragment and at last get all datas in the Fragment number 6 which would be a kind of summary of all datas.

If you know how to do it it could be great.

The Drawer and All the XML are OK, I can pass a single data from one fragment to another one but When I want to add another data from another fragment, the app crash.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    /* ******* Déclaration des différents composants de l'appli : la Toolbar,
    le Drawer et le Navigation View **********************************  */

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        /* **** Concerne le FAB d'origine du modèle de GOOGLE **********
        *****************************************************************
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        */

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new IntroFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_introduction);
        }
    }

    /* **** Referme le Drawer lorsqu'on clic sur le Hamburger *********
    ***************************************************************** */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        /* ******* Desactivation du menu SETTING pour le moment ********
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }*/

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /* *** Gère l'affichage des Fragments dans le Drawer *********
    ************************************************************** */
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Gère les clics sur les panneaux dans le Drawer.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_introduction:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new IntroFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_technicien:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new TechnicienFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_dossier:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new DossierFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_date:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new DateFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_zone:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ZoneFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_intervention:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new InterventionFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_photo:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new PhotoFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_recapitulatif:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new RecapitulatifFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_photo) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_introduction) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_technicien) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_dossier) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_date) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_zone) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_intervention) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not the way you wanna do but anyway, make a global static list and add values to it....again this is not ideal

Comment: How Can I add Values from different fragment in a static list ?? The datas are on 5 differents fragments and I would like to show them in Fragment 6.

Comment: make a static list List<AnyModel> list = new ....(), and every time you open/do the transaction on those fragments, you add values to list.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, fragments do not have direct access to each other and must use the containing view to transfer data back and forth.  I suggest you check this pre-existing and already-answered question.   [Passing data from one fragment to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568339/passing-data-from-one-fragment-to-another)

But the main idea is you have to pass the data back to the main view and when it gets it, it passes it on to the other fragment.

Comment: Thx, it's working for a single Fragment yes but When I go to another Fragment using the Drawer and click on the button on this other fragment, the app crash

Comment: use interface, define in your host activity, and communicate it through

Comment: to be clearer, you pass data from the fragment to the main view with an interface.  You pass from the main view to the fragment with intent extras.

Comment: Thx for the answer, how can you define this kind of Interface ? i am kinda new in Android for Fragments